# ﬁnd the general solution to the linear system and conﬁrm that the row vectors of the coefﬁcient matrix are orthogonal to the solution vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

im not sure how to answer this question completely. all i can think of is to use guasian elimination but they seem like theyd all just cancel out, and there is a solution in the back of the book. I'm pretty stuck here..

Comment: After Gauss elimination, only the first equation remains. What can you say about the space of all solutions?

Comment: i don't know.. they are parallel?

Comment: Can you find at least *one* solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the first equation is relavant, the others don't bring any additional information. The first equation says that the solution vector $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ is perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$ (if you are familiar with the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)). The set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$ is a two-dimensional plane. In particular, there are infinitely many solutions.

Now the problem is that you cannot write down a list of infinitely many elements, so you need to describe or encode them somehow. The encoding $\{(x_1, x_2, x_3): \,x_1+x_2+x_3=0\}$ is, in fact, one of the most concise descriptions, altgouth this is tautological. If you are familiar with vector spaces and basis, you can also describe it as the span of two independent solutions $\langle (1,-1,0), (0,1,-1)\rangle$ (a geometric plane that contains the origin is a span of two independent vectors).